# Python Pip install another package into site-packages with the same module name existing in that folder

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

For example, I already have a module named `test1` in my site-packages folder, `test1` already toke that folder name under `site-packages`

Now I have another package, using the module name `test1.subModule1`, I decided to install this new package without destroy the structure of the above one.

Can I do that?
If yes, I need a solution in maybe `setup.py` in both module, to tell both module sharing the same top-level module name: MERGE FILE not overwrite. Is there a solution anther than `namespace` to achieve this goal?

Thanks

Comment: Is `test1` a folder inside `site-packages` already provided by `test1` package?  If for whatever reason `test1` module is provided by a file called `test1.py` it will lead to issues, otherwise what you want to achieve is entirely possible.

Comment: @metatoaster `test1` is a folder in site-packages, not a file. `test1` already have `submodule3` and `submodule2` in that folder

Comment: Then in the package that supplied `test1`, the `setup.py` should include that directory as a namespace package, e.g. `namespace_packages=['test1']`, likewise for the new package `test1.submodule1`.

Comment: No I canot use namespace here, for I have already a function `test1.Initialize()` registerd. for which namespace cannot have functions.

Comment: The only way you can have multiple packages share a top level namespace(s) is to have all packages involved agreed on the namespace(s) that need to be shared between them, and thus it is not possible to have an `__init__.py` for `test1`. Please refer [to this documentation](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#native-namespace-packages) - modern `pip` and the wheel packaging method have defaulted to native namespace packages, the other two methods below are generally unsupported (they automatically convert to native) by modern package management tools.

Comment: No solution that I know of. As mentioned already the closest you can get is to use (native) namespace packages. -- Otherwise maybe you could build something yourself, if you feel like this is really what you want to do and understand the risks. If you write the code, and encounter issues, then feel free to ask a question and maybe we can help you. If there is no code from your side then we can not really help.